# Remap a Modified Key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys

How can I remap a modified key such as CTRL-j to another key (possibly modified), while leaving the key j alone?

I am  using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: can you explain little more specific what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu, keyboard shortcuts can be managed through 'Settings Editor' and 'Keyboard'. These programs can be respectively installed by

sudo apt install xfce4-settings-editor

sudo apt install xfce4-keyboard-settings

In xfce4-keyboard-settings (the simpler program), go to the 'Application Shortcuts' tab and double-click on the shortcut that you want to edit, presumably Ctrl+J, then edit the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the remapper deamon [keyd](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd) for this purpose. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1364828/13884) for installation, usage and tips.

After installation, use the config below. It makes left control activate a layer `controlj` while held, where every thing you press is be default modified by control (the `:C`), except for the key(s) remapped in the layer---in this case only `j`, which is remapped to `Shift + j`.

You can throw other modifiers on there, e.g. `j = M-A-C-S-j` for `Meta + Alt + Control + Shift + j`.

```
[ids]

*

[main]

leftcontrol = layer(controlj)

[controlj:C]

j = S-j
```